# Has anybody published any C# 4 coding standards / guidelines / style guides?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, coding-style

I'm aware of a number of coding standards and guidelines for C# 2 and C# 3 but am looking for some which have been written with C# 4 in mind.

Comment: Just had a look at www.idesign.net, they have a good coding standard document, but hasnt been updated recently...

Comment: @Mark Redman: In particular, it says nothing specifically about C# 4.0 or even 2.0 and 3.0, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm in the process of publishing new coding guidelines for C# 4.0 [here](http://csharpguidelines.codeplex.com/releases/view/46280).

Answer (score 2):

Try the new Edition of [Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321658701).

Answer (score 0):

I have found recently [this article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/code-contracts-csharp) about code contracts in C# 4.0 which is part of [C# in Depth, Second Edition](http://www.manning.com/skeet2/) book.

Comment: @Tomi: I suspect tjrobinson is after something broaded, covering "when to use optional parameters" etc. While I do give *some* guidance in C# in Depth, it's not quite the same. Still, if he finds it handy, then great :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Well, in "What's inside" of your book is said "Guidance and practical experience" and "Not just the What and How, but the Why" so I think it covers this question pretty good :)

Comment: I definitely give guidance - but if I were looking for *just* a coding standards document, I wouldn't want to have to wade through a whole book :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet is right, I'm after something a few pages long, which we can tweak for our needs, and developers here can all use as a quick reference for coding standards. I'm not after the level of detail you get in a book like C# in Depth (which I own and recommend).